sum of cubes of digits equal to the number - not working for 153 but working fine for others when storing result in int
The code below computes the sum of cubes of digits of a number and check if the sum and the number itself are equal. when declaring s1 as int I don't get the desired result for 153(but it works fine for 370, 371 and 407) but when s1 is double there is no problem. Can someone explain why?
int s1;
for(i=140; i<=500; i++){
    tmp=i; s1=0;
    while(tmp!=0){
        s1+=pow((tmp%10), 3);
        tmp=tmp/10;
    }
    printf("i=%d s=%d ", i, s1);
    if(s1==i) printf("%d is cubic\n", i);
    else printf("\n");
}


Aside: please don't use pow() to cube an integer. If you working with double then printf will round it, but assignig to an integer will truncate say 26.9999999 to 26.

@WeatherVane Should that really be an "aside"? It may be the reason for the problem.

Does it work as expected if you use int digit = tmp%10; s1 += digit*digit*digit;?

@WeatherVane but how it works for 371 which also its 1 is cubed using pow and int?

@Barmar yes it works fine like this s1 += digitdigitdigit;

If you want to see why it's happening, print the values of (int)pow((tmp%10), 3). Or print pow((tmp%10), 3) with lots of digits after the decimal.

If it works for 370, but not 153, the problem is probably with pow(5, 3).

@Barmar it works even with 371 which has the digit 1. for printing the values. if u use %d it show 0 but if u use %f it show 1.zeroes

Try using %.20f to see all the digits.

also for 153, the resulting sum is 152 so the problem is probably with 1

Actually, that's what I used (i mean %.20f) and it is 1.zeroes

“so the problem is probably with 1” No, the problem they’ve mentioned could reduce any cube by 1. Try the correction: int d = tmp % 10; s1 += d * d * d;

@Ry- yes that solution works fine and I'm aware of it. The thing that feels weird is why the 1 of 153 was reduced but not the 1 of 371. Anyways, I will try to avoid using pow as much as I can after facing this output

As Barmar said, the difference between those is the digit 5, not the digit 1.

With the comments doing the mapping onto this question (in short pow() being the culprit), I close as duplicate of something explaining the deeper science.
